# Python/Selenium - text property of WebElement truncates duplicating whitespaces

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

I would like to share my observation related with **text** property of *WebElement*. I have a pdf link:
[image]

The file name has triple whitespace and when I try to get **text** property of the element enclosed in tag , just receive truncated string from extra whitespaces:

*"03057895_05-01-2015_platform express array induction sp gr hsts neutron density log.pdf"*

And it comes for me very critical to find out this issue, cause I used **text** to identify the downloaded file name and monitor the download status of the file.

Anybody have encountered something like that previously or maybe know why is it work in a such a manner?

Comment: I don't know how this is handled in Selenium, but whitespace is not preserved generally in html, so it wouldn't surprise me if non-rendered parts were cleaned up for you. . . can you not use the href in the link since that has to be correct and would be more reliable I assume

Comment: hm... You didn't get my point. My complaint is that **text** property has unpredictable behavior in this case. Though this extra whitespace is a problem of the html, I thought selenium should return actual result without any implicit manipulations.
--
P.S. I'm not using href, I'm trying to extract text of tag <a>, cause it is going to be a filename after downloading and this consequently turns to me as an issue, cause **text** returns non-existing filename

Comment: No, I don't think I misunderstood.  That is the area in which white space is not significant and not necessarily preserved, especially when asking the renderer

Comment: I do not render anything (by the way, this extra whitespaces is rendered by browser as it is, without trimming). And actually this is significant, cause this link is a pdf file name, which I'm trying to download. And this **text()** property seemed to me as the simplest solution to get it out from the _WebElement_ object, but surprisingly it did wrong IMHO, because of these trimming things under it. This is unexpected result, cause in my opinion *text()* property is designed to return a pure text value enclosed in tag _<a></a>_ or whatever (I highlighted it with yellow), but it returns edited

Comment: The part between the `<a>` tags is exactly what selenium is "rendering" and the area in which white space is not reliable.  If you want the actual name the only safe thing to do is to get the `href` part of the `a` tag and process that.

Comment: yep, that was my actual workaround for it, you're right:

`url = pdf_link.get_attribute('href')
 filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace('%20', ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

As @Eric commented, this is not a problem of selenium. It is an issue in your application.
However, if you really want to get that text, you have to get attribute innerHTML. See code below:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: I tried to figure out some other things. And your example is very rough, as you can see this <a> is deeply nested in the DOM, see [link](https://snag.gy/E0XbAn.jpg). This is a table, and in order to handle each link only with PDF extension, we should loop through each table row <tr> and then find the proper column <td> and only after that indicate the tag <a> with exact url and finally my willing was getting simple text entry of this <a> by using **text** property. I'm not sure that _css_selector_ suits here

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov I'm not sure if I understand you or not. You can create css selector expression that match `<a>` which contains the exact URL in the table. e.g. `"table > tbody a[href*='.pdf']"`. Why don't you use this?

Comment: css_selector returns WebElement object, I need it's text attribute, cause this is actual file name, which afterwards I'm going to monitor whether it's downloading finished

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov do you try my answer yet? It returns text, not a webelement.

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't got it yet. What css selector you are talking about, all `find_by_` methods always return WebElement object, you can then get `get_attribute('href')` of it and then strip to a file name as I actually did and @Eric Renouf proposed

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov My answer is to get_attribute('innerHTML'). I'm not sure what you are referring to.  Could you copy&paste what you can see in my answer here?

Comment: My friend, _WebElement_ object and even HTML tag don't have such an attribute _innerHTML_, this won't work in Python. If have already chromedriver.exe executable installed, try this snippet: https://ideone.com/8VZcii

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov I have no idea what you are talking about at all. innerHTML is a [standard DOM property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp). See [result](http://www.buaban.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/innerHTML.png) from Python on my machine. I've modified the content of webpage via chrome devtool then find the element and print the innerHTML attribute.

Comment: Very funny, you've modified the content of HTML. Actually, this is not my case. I showed you exact situation where it doesn't work at all without any implicit HTML modification. If you had tried running my code, you would have seen that, it's pretty simple. And css selector have no advantage here, we could use any locator to identify _WebElement_

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov 1. My answer is not about CssSelector, it is about "innerHTML". You can use any kinds of locator as you want. Then, 2. you can get attribute "innerHTML" to get text that contains multiple whitespaces without truncation. Finally, you can compare the filename. I have create a new page for you [here](http://www.buaban.com/test-whitespace-for-alexpbogdanov/) and my code works fine.